# Having User Settings and Project Settings separately in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

We are working on a python based project and our vscode setting.json contains lots of great stuff, like Unit Test settings, but it also contains python path, which this is more related to a user specific machine.

Is there a way to move Python Path somewhere else?

```
    "azureFunctions.projectLanguage": "Python",
    "azureFunctions.projectRuntime": "~2",
    "azureFunctions.preDeployTask": "func: pack",
    "python.pythonPath": "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/bin/python",
    "python.testing.unittestArgs": [
        "-v",
        "tests",
        "-t", 
        ".",
        "-p",
        "*_test.py"
    ],
```

I want to move `python.pythonPath` somewhere else so when other open the project, it won't keep asking for the python runtime. So where would this go?

Comment: move it to your `.vscode/settings.json` or use the Settings UI to change the Workspace settings. But then you check it in and other users have a problem not find the python exe. Keep it in the User settings and other suff in the `.vscode` directory

Comment: You can use environment variables, https://medium.com/@reuvenharrison/using-visual-studio-code-to-debug-a-go-program-with-environment-variables-523fea268271

Answer (score 0):

There currently isn't a way to get what you're after currently, but please  [the feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/2125) that would solve this for you.